# Почему MongoDB использует всю оперативную память?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Последние два дня MongoDB начинает пожирать оперативку по нарастающей.
В итоге к концу дня сервис MongoDB просто падает.
Выглядит это вот так.
[image: RAM Usage]

Comment: Ось то какая, м?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: в те моменты, когда спад (4 окт) - что то делалось?

Comment: Вы в логи пробовали смотреть? Без них никак не разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

[by design](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-require-a-lot-of-ram).

> MongoDB automatically uses all free memory on the machine as its
>   cache.

MongoDB автоматически использует всю свободную оперативную память для кеширования.

Comment: Но ведь к падению это не должно приводить?

Comment: На серверах с небольшим количеством памяти такое происходит. Не должно - согласен, но происходит :) Возможно сервер не справляется с огромным количеством дисковых операций чтения/записи. Возможно за память начинают бороться другие сервисы.

Comment: сервер свой или vps? у vps нормальная практика во время критических ошибок задачу прибивать.

Comment: @hitcode вроде был vps